# Can't log files to my express server, how do I do it?

Tags: reactjs, express, file, file-upload, server

I am doing a react component where you upload a pdf to my server, the issue is that the file field (where the file is supposed to be stored) is coming empty (when logging the body in my server's console), and when finding a solution, as changing the header, I get an error like this: Error: Multipart: Boundary not found, and when the boundary is added; I get this error: Error: Unexpected end of form.

I have tried for hours but nothing has worked, so I'll leave the code of both the react component and the express server (which are probably full of errors since I have being modyfing it for hours trying to find a solution), and hopely someone will help me.

## Express server

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'C:\\Users\\Propietario\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\pdf-files');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'application/pdf') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({ 
  storage: storage, 
  fileFilter: fileFilter 
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(upload.single('file'));

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).send('No file was uploaded or the file type is not supported.');
  }

  const fileName = req.file.originalname;

  res.send(`File ${fileName} was uploaded and stored as ${req.file.filename}.`);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

## react component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const App = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const handleDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const droppedFile = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    if (droppedFile.type === 'application/pdf') {
      setFile(droppedFile);
    } else {
      alert('Only PDFs are allowed.');
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setFile(null);
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
  const boundary = uuidv4();

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  formData.append('name', file.name);

  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundary}` },
      

    });
    const result = await response.text();
    alert(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert('Failed to upload the file.');
  }
};
  

  return (
    <div
      onDrop={handleDrop}
      onDragOver={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
      style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        border: '1px solid black',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      {file ? (
        <>
          <p>{file.name}</p>
          <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
          <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
        </>
      ) : (

        <p>Drop a PDF file here</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Two issues. Unless you really have a reason, you don't need to set the `Content-Type` header with `fetch` when sending a file. Second, your `boundary` is not valid as `uuid` creates a 128 bits of 16bit UTF8 string while the `boundary` is limited to 72 bits of 7bit ASCII characters. So, you should be fine if you just remove the `headers` option from your `fetch()` call.